# Webkit CSS Animation Jumping issue

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have an animation set up with two rotating boxes, smaller box within a larger box. It uses JS to add classes to animate, pause and resume.

In Webkit, the problem I'm encountering is on mouseout, which adds a pause class and pauses the CSS Animation, the animation jumps back to its initial state. Sometimes it jumps as if the animation never paused. I've tried animation-fill and adding in the end animation state. Everything I've searched for and tried did not seem to help.

Any help is appreciated.

Entire Code is here
https://jsfiddle.net/qQcFy/105/

CSS Animation Code

```
@-webkit-keyframes circle {
    from {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes inner-circle {
    from {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

#rotator.is-rotating {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-animation: circle 55s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#rotator.is-rotating.is-paused {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}

#rotator .box.is-rotating {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    -webkit-animation: inner-circle 55s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

#rotator .box.is-rotating.is-paused {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 12px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:#ccc;
    text-align:center;
}

.box-small {
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    display: block !important;
    height: 46px;
    width: 47px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add...

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

...to anything you are transitioning. Supposed to work based on this documentation [**here**](https://davidwalsh.name/translate3d)...